# Can't find / Missing Windows option in Visual Studio

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4Tv8.png)

Newbie VS user here, (not really but using after years) I can't find the windows option in Visual Studio Code. I want to use it to reset the windows layout bur=t struggling from past 2-3 days finding one option. The Internet doesn't seem to have a Idea on this either. Please Guide if you can & also another question in here (if you wish to answer) is How do I find Solution Explorer tab also.

Thank you for the time.
Have a Great Day!

I wanted to start a project but couldn't find Solution Explorer tab, hence now I am trying to Reset all window layout but can't find that option too.

Comment: VSC has no Solution Explorer

Comment: VSCode and Visual Studio are 2 completely different products with a similar name. Solution Explorer is in Visual Studio (Community, Enterprise, Pro, Express) and not in VSCode. Also at StackOverflow the `Visual Studio` name and tag refer to Visual Studio  (Community, Enterprise, Pro, Express) and not VSCode.